# Node redirect after saving to db

Tags: node.js, express

Im doing a node app, which has a html form doing an action to `/users`
This url calls this method on post

```
  exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    } else {
      res.status(302).json(user).redirect('/chat');
    }
  });

};
```

However i'm unable to do a redirect after storing the data in my db, and get the error `Can't set headers after they are sent.`

I've tried placing the redirect different places in the form, but i keep getting the same error.

Comment: `Can't set headers after they are sent` means you are sending the response twice

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `.json(user)` from the `redirect`. You cannot both send a JSON and a redirect at the same time.

Or if you want to send the JSON, maybe as a response to an Ajax request, don't send `.status(302)` but do the redirect on client side JavaScript.